# 1TB HDD making strange noise (not a common one)

Tags: hard-drive, noise

I built a new PC some days ago, and everything seems perfect, except that the 1 TB HDD I cloned from my old 500 GB HDD is making a deep weird sound. First of all, every time I access the disk, [I hear a deep sound](http://chirb.it/FBPrke), and when the PC is turning on, [I hear some clicking](http://chirb.it/hmaAt9) **(the rapid clicking is my mouse, I'm opening and closing folders to trigger the vibrating deep weird sound I'm describing)**. I'm using this 1TB disk for data mainly (I use a SSD as the OS).

As background information, the disk is a seagate barracuda 7200 rpm which was RMAd and replaced with a refurbished one. Maybe the refurbished disks make these noises? should I worry about my data? (although the disk is working normal and passed a seagatetools short generic test? Thanks!

PS: I recorded the sounds, just click on the links. Thanks

**UPDATE**: I finally reduced the possibilities of this humming noise to *vibration*. Concluded this by taking the HDD out and placing it in a mat as suggested by @Synetech. The vibration can be also because I changed the surface where the computer is. Back then I had it in a carpet, and know I have it in a wooden-surface (aka computer desk).

Comment: The clicking sound is bad but does the deep noise sound like the disk could be vibrating? I had that happen once and it was because one of the clamp screws was loose - just a couple of screwdriver turns and the problem was fixed.

Comment: You should always worry about your data if you do not have it backed up somewhere else.

Comment: The first recording sounds almost like typical thrashing and/or unusual vibrating. The second recording doesn’t sound unusual; it is normal for the drive to click when powering up and wheeze while spinning up.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought the same, about the vibration. I took the drive away a tried to reposition it. My case has some "brackets" to put the harddrive without screws and just slide the drive, but so far that vibration didnt stop. Should I worry about it? Im starting to think I should change the disk. (although it is almost new!)

Comment: Where is the hard-drive? Try putting it outside the case, on a soft mat (like a mouse-pad). Try holding it or lightly putting your hand on it. So you feel strong vibrations or does it stop when it’s on a something soft (that absorbs vibrations)? Does it do it when booting or only when accessing the drive? I’m assuming that this is the same model as your previous one and the old one did not do this right?

Comment: *> I'm using this 1TB disk for data mainly (I use a SSD as the OS).*   As a side note, I’ll point out that you are (probably) doing it backwards. You should put the OS on the hard-drive and the data on the SSD. The OS does a lot of writes and creates lots of temporary files which is bad for SSDs as opposed to data (especially backups/archives) which is not modified as often. Further, OS files are easily replaceable as opposed to file you create which are irreplaceable. Put your data on your most reliable drive.

Comment: Ok, I took the disk out and put it on a fluffy white plastic surface (really soft, its like "plastic wrapping paper" used to envelope goods) and the odd sound is gone. But I did touch the disk while accessing it and I feel things moving (not the regular spinning but like the disk moving backwards and upwards when accessing the files). I don't know if this is normal, nor I can describe it really accurately I'm afraid. Is it worth it to put some of this wrapping plastic on the side of the brackets, to "terminate" this vibration? Thanks!.

Comment: As a side note, I have to point out that my last drive was in the top part of the mount for the hard drives on my case, and now it's on the bottom. This change I believe, made the vibration much more notorious. Thanks!. Also, about the OS in the SSD, I do this mainly for the speed of booting and overall speed of programs! Also, the most valuable data I have are scanned documents and writings alongside with some lots of pictures and music. These files will be stored in the SSD for sure. The rest (downloads, some games), will be on the mechanical drive. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Synetech yes, because all my documents, movies and musics really benefit from the extra read speed and low latency of the SSD... anyway, that's a debate for another day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description and tests, it sounds like that particular model of drive [just happens to](https://www.google.com/search?q=seagate+barracuda+1tb+noise) [vibrate more than average](https://www.google.com/search?q=seagate+barracuda+1tb+vibration) (high vibration is normal for a 10,000RPM drive, but even a 7,200 can be kind of noisy).

Try mounting it with some rubber grommets/shims ([or something](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/disk-drives/f/3534/p/19393187/19920288.aspx#19920288)) to absorb the vibration instead of passing it through to the case. Also, if the case has hard-plastic feet, replace them with rubber ones or put the whole thing on a soft surface (keeping airflow in mind). If the sound and vibration are reduced to nominal levels, then it is probably not something to be worried about (only annoyed at).

If you are concerned about the health of the drive, check the SMART data (e.g. with [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) or SeaTools),  to see if there are any warnings about its actual health since any delays in spin up and such would be logged there; though it is probably [going to check out as okay](http://forums.seagate.com/t5/Barracuda-XT-Barracuda-Barracuda/ST31000528AS-7200-12-1TB-humming-vibrations/m-p/88522).

(Based on the following description from [someone else with this issue](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgXmVqSKxKw), it may be due to a slight misalignment.)

> Oscillating hum. it makes a loud hum that then gets soft, then goes back to loud. this cycle (that is about 3 seconds long)

Comment: Yep, I checked the drive with lots of tests (including a SMART report), and the drive is more than fine. I have also concluded that this vibration is multiplied by the surface the computer is laying (wooden surface vs fluffy carpet). I might as well try the "suspending the drive with rubbers" method, although I have to admit it looks insecure hahaha. Thanks for all the input and interest in the issue @Synetech

Comment: No problem. I actually put a piece of rubbery carpet under-padding under my computer to absorb the vibrations of my drives and fans.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: I guess it was the mouse; if your drive makes that noise though, its about to die and see below :).**

That sound is the disk head attempting to find a read location. I've run into this several times. A death is always around the corner for the disk.

"The clicking sound itself arises from the unexpected movement of the disk's read-write actuator. At startup, and during use, the disk head must move correctly and be able to confirm it is correctly tracking data on the disk. If the head fails to move as expected or upon moving cannot track the disk surface correctly, the disk controller may attempt to recover from the error by aborting the operation, at times causing an audible "click". In some devices, the process automatically retries causing a repeated clicking sound.

...

On a hard disk drive, the click of death refers to a similar phenomenon; the head actuator may click or knock as the drive repetitively tries to recover from one or more errors. These sounds can be the heads repetitively loading or unloading, or they can be the sounds of the actuator striking a stop, or both. The click of death can signal the hard drive has crashed or failed." From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_of_death).

In either case, I would not use the drive; that or keep a good backup. Of course, you should always have [a good backup](http://data-backup-software-review.toptenreviews.com/why-backup-your-computer.html) :)

Comment: Did you listen to the recording? The clicking on power-on is normal, and the high-pitched clicking in the second one is just the mouse.

Comment: The rapid initial clicking? Yes, that sounded like the click of death.

Comment: Ohh hahaha what a misunderstanding, in the "deep sound", the rapid clicking is myself opening and closing folders files to "trigger" the deep sound thing. It can be hear in both recordings.

Comment: Oh. Well then I recend my comment :) sounds exactly like the click of death.

Comment: The click is my mouse! haha

Comment: You should have two good backups, one in a different place.